# Generic Queries with Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a Entity model that includes a large number of lookup entities. All have just ID and Name properties.

I do not want to build large number of DAL classes to simply have something like:

```
IList<Lookup1> lookup1List= ctx.Lookup1.ToList();
```

and another class (Or method) with

```
IList<Lookup2> lookup2List= ctx.Lookup2.ToList();
```

and another with

```
IList<Lookup3> lookup3List= ctx.Lookup3.ToList();
```

I want to have one generic way to query all them using an interface they all Implement.
Something like

```
IList<ILookupEntity> list = "SomeMethod"(Type lookupType);
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this?

```
public class Repository<T> where T : EntityObject, new()
{
    public static IQueryable<T> List()
    {
        return EntityContext.Current.CreateObjectSet<T>();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var lookups = Repository<Lookup1>.List();
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this work With Self tracking Entities (who do not inherit from EntityObject) ?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to query all objects that implement a specific interface? I don't think that's possible, currently.